# How should we give privileges/permissions to group to access different db's

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm new to working on RDS postgresql instance, I've a group and added a couple of users to the group. I need to give permission to users in the group to allow them to access other dbs like x ,y and z

I logged in as admin user to y database and gave permission to the group, but the user is not able to view tables in other dbs. Group name is dev_role. All tables are in public schema.

```
y=> ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER ON TABLES TO dev_role;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
```

Even Tried

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO dev_role;
```

The user logged into y db and was trying to run `\dt`, the user is getting an error:

```
Did not find any relations.
```

> psql (10.11, server 11.5)

What could be the issue and can someone point me correct way to give permissions.

Comment: When the user did \dt , he got that error

Comment: While connected to database y, you can never access tables in other databases. Is that your problem? I still don't understand what you are doing. To which database are you connected when you do `\dt`? Are there any tables? If yes, in which schema?

Comment: He was connected to y database and he was trying to access tables in that db. The tables are in public schema

Comment: Then the `search_path` must have been messed up. Try `SET search_path = public` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one thing, there is no difference between regular PostgreSQL and RDS PostgreSQL when it comes to `ROLES`,`GRANT`, `PRIVILEGES`, and `GRANT`. In your case, the user must be connecting to other than y DB. Maybe he connection default DB Postgres.  Tested in my rds instance.

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO dev_role;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO dev_role;
```

with this working fine for me, ref.[docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-grant.html):

```
y=> \dt
         List of relations
 Schema |  Name  | Type  |  Owner   
--------+--------+-------+----------
 public | table1 | table | postgres
 public | table2 | table | postgres
(2 rows)
```

and when I connected to other than `y` DB,

```
postgres=> \dt
No relations found.
```

Since you didn't give permission here.